# Web API on IIS7.5 Unable to download * from localhost

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I'm currently trying to install web api project directly from vs 2013 to my local dev machine, but when I test one of my http get controllers, I get the following:

[image]

My url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/Location/States?queryTerm=Ark
```

When I test this on my local, this url works and I get my json response.

pay no attention to the web config error in the background. If I enter anything invalid, I get an IIS error, so I know I'm hitting the right URL.

Side note: I'm using IE8 for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution, and it may be a config thing, but when I made this as an virtual application to a website, this went away, and it gave me a yellow sign of death (which is a good thing). I was able to deduce this to be an oracle issue, where it couldn't find the database connection, and then found out it couldn't resolve tns names.

So I guess Web API can not be hosted by itself on IIS? I haven't looked into it, but it seems this to be the case, unless there needs to be more tweaking involved.

Answer (score 0):

i know too late for response. But i get same error when I try deploy Odata v4 Application in IIS server. 
In server , i hit this error as above, i try everything config but nothing change.
At last, i try connect from client and it work.
I recognize that in Client , it download a json file from Server (in case use Odata , it seem like wsdl file in webservice) and API still work well.

For some reason, it cant download in server, but dont worry, it still work.
Hope this helps!